# Adding pagination with the help of progress bar in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, pagination

I am developing a application in which I have firebase database as my backend. I have added a recyclerview to show the retrieved data from firebase in a cardview. I want to add pagination to recyclerview, it should load first 3 card then after scroll next 3 card and so on. But I am not able to do that, I got only first three cards as expected and when database called again after scroll it gives out all the data stored in database including the first three cars same as above. What is problem here? I am posting my code below.

This the code for Search Profile:

```
public class Search_Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Firebase firebase;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    LinearLayoutManager manager;
    Boolean isScrolling = false;
    int currentitems, totalitems, scrolloutitems;
    String oldestPostId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_detail);
        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Search_Profile.this));

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Search_Profile.this);

        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data from Firebase Database");
        progressDialog.show();


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Dashboard.Database_Path);
        databaseReference.limitToFirst(3).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    oldestPostId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    snapshot.getChildrenCount();

                    assert user != null;
                    list.add(user);
                }
                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(Search_Profile.this, list);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {

                    isScrolling = true;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                currentitems = manager.getChildCount();
                totalitems = manager.getItemCount();
                scrolloutitems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (isScrolling && (currentitems + scrolloutitems == totalitems)) {

                    isScrolling = false;
                    fetchData();
                    Toast.makeText(Search_Profile.this, "On Load Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void fetchData() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

                    progressDialog.show();
                    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                                oldestPostId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                                snapshot.getChildrenCount();

                                assert user != null;
                                list.add(user);
                            }
                            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(Search_Profile.this, list);

                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    Toast.makeText(Search_Profile.this, "Load on fetchData()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

This is code for RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
  public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    Firebase firebase;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Context context;
    List<User> MainImageUploadInfoList;

    RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<User> TempList) {
        this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final User user = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setTag(user.getUser_id());
        holder.getLayoutPosition();
        holder.mCardView.setTag(position);
        holder.FirstNameTextView.setText(user.getFirst_name() + " " + user.getLast_name());
        holder.DateTextView.setText(user.getDate());
        holder.HeightTextView.setText(user.getHeight());
        holder.EducationTextView.setText(user.getHighest_education());
        holder.OccupationTextView.setText(user.getOccupation());
        holder.UserIDTextView.setText(user.getUser_id());
        holder.income.setText(user.getIncome());
        holder.city_state.setText(user.getCity_state());
        holder.hobbies.setText(user.getHobbies());
        holder.marital_status.setText(user.getMarital_status());
        holder.family_members.setText(user.getFamily_members());
        holder.mothers_name.setText(user.getMothers_name());
        holder.fathers_name.setText(user.getFathers_name());
        holder.fathers_occupation.setText(user.getFathers_occupation());
        holder.mothers_occupation.setText(user.getMothers_occupation());
        holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        User user = new User();
        public TextView FirstNameTextView;
        public TextView DateTextView;
        public TextView HeightTextView;
        public TextView EducationTextView;
        public TextView OccupationTextView;
        public TextView UserIDTextView;
        public Button send_invitation,shortlist_profile;
        public TextView income;
        public TextView city_state;
        public TextView hobbies;
        public TextView marital_status;
        public TextView family_members;
        public TextView mothers_name;
        public TextView fathers_name;
        public TextView fathers_occupation;
        public TextView mothers_occupation;
        public CardView mCardView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview1);
            FirstNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            DateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            HeightTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            EducationTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            OccupationTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            UserIDTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            income = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.income);
            city_state = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_state);
            hobbies = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hobbies);
            marital_status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.marital_status);
            family_members = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.family_members);
            mothers_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mothers_name);
            fathers_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fathers_name);
            fathers_occupation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fathers_occupation);
            mothers_occupation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mothers_occupation);
            send_invitation = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendinvitation);
            shortlist_profile=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.shortlistprofile);
            send_invitation=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendinvitation);
            shortlist_profile=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.shortlistprofile);
            shortlist_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    FirebaseUser user1 = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    String userId = user1.getUid();
                    Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://baghbanshadi-25553.firebaseio.com/");
                    Firebase userRef = rootRef.child("User");
                    User user =new User();
                    String user_id=UserIDTextView.getText().toString();
                    assert user != null;
                    user.setUser_id(user_id);
                    userRef.child(userId).child("Shortlisted").child(user_id).setValue(user_id);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Profile Shortlisted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }); mCardView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final int position = (int) itemView.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (getLayoutPosition() == 0) {
                final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("positionGroup", position);
                context.startActivity(it);

            } else if (getLayoutPosition() == 1) {
                final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("positionGroup", position);
                context.startActivity(it);

            } else if (getLayoutPosition() == 2) {
                final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("positionGroup", position);
                context.startActivity(it);
            }else if (getLayoutPosition() == 3) {
                final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("positionGroup", position);
                context.startActivity(it);
            }else if (getLayoutPosition() == 4) {
                final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("positionGroup", position);
                context.startActivity(it);
            }else if (getLayoutPosition() == 5) {
                final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());

                it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("positionGroup", position);
                context.startActivity(it);
            }else if (getLayoutPosition() == 6) {
                final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("positionGroup", position);
                context.startActivity(it);
            }else if (getLayoutPosition() == 7) {
                final Intent it = new Intent(v.getContext(), ViewProfile.class);
                it.putExtra("first_name", FirstNameTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("date", DateTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("height", HeightTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("city_state", city_state.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("hobbies", hobbies.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("highest_education", EducationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("occupation", OccupationTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("income", income.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("marital_status", marital_status.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("family_members", family_members.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_name", fathers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_name", mothers_name.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("fathers_occupation", fathers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("mothers_occupation", mothers_occupation.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("user_id", UserIDTextView.getText().toString());
                it.putExtra("positionGroup", position);
                context.startActivity(it);
                            }}}}
```

Comment: Use _ViewTypes_ for that

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/24041/android-recyclerview-load-more-endless-scrolling